# how to write package name in android manifest?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am working on my application now i had created three packages in my application and i put this three package in one particular package and i had updated Android Manifest but still it will force closed.I had tried lots of things but no working please help me.
How to solve that? 
Android Manifest

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="mayank.com"
     android:versionCode="1"
     android:versionName="1.0" >

    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="mayank.com.onlinerecharge.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:theme="@style/tabTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
       </activity>
      <activity android:name="mayank.com.onlinerecharge.signup" />
       <activity android:name="mayank.com.onlinerecharge.signin" />
    <activity android:name="mayank.com.onlinerecharge.account"
         android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:theme="@style/tabTheme"/>
    <activity android:name="mayank.com.onlinerecharge.mobile" />
    <activity android:name="mayank.com.onlinerecharge.dth" />
    <activity android:name="mayank.com.onlinerecharge.datacard" />
    <activity android:name="mayank.com.onlinerecharge.about" />
    <activity android:name="mayank.com.onlinerecharge.ViewPagerAdapter" />
    <activity android:name="mayank.com.after_login.Main_after_login"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
                 android:theme="@style/tabTheme" />
    <activity android:name="mayank.com.after_login.help" />
    <activity android:name="mayank.com.after_login.history" />
    <activity android:name="mayank.com.after_login.ewallet" />
    <activity android:name="mayank.com.after_login.signout" />
    <activity android:name="mayank.com.utils.Const" />
    <activity android:name="mayank.com.utils.Pref" />
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
         </manifest>
```

Comment: put your Manifest filehere

Comment: Please post Manifest file here.

Comment: also your package detaisl

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{mayank.com/mayank.com.onlinerecharge.account}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{mayank.com/mayank.com.onlinerecharge.signin}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Whenever you ask question on stackoverflow, make sure you include possible code, snaps, logcat output. It will help us to understand your issue.

Comment: now help me what should be problem

Comment: is this in your Manifest file `package="......."`?

Comment: This is problem`NullPointerException ` you have null value in your code in `mayank.com.onlinerecharge.account` activity.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have your package and absolute path to the activity defined incorrectly.  Another thing to note: packages are typically com.mayank... not mayank.com.

Check the path to 'signin' against it's definition in the Manifest and consider changing it to just ".onlinerecharge.signin".

Also, please, please, please press CTRL-F (COMMAND-F for Macs) before you save your code so it'll be properly formatted ;)

Answer (score 0):

generally package names are start with com.mayank like that. in this scenario your are forgot to mention your package name fully. I think your package name is "mayank.com.onlinerecharge" . but instead you write only mayank.com only. comming to activities your mentioned full package name.so correct it.